# Correctly extend Object class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, pojo

I would like to take a record (plain Javascript object) of arrays and embelish it with some additional properties/methods, preferably by creating a new instance of a class:

```
class Dataframe extends Object {
  _nrow: number;
  _ncol: number;
  _identity: number[];

  constructor(values: Record<string, any[]>) {
    super();
    this._nrow = values[Object.keys(values)[0]].length;
    this._ncol = Object.keys(values).length;
    this._identity = Array(this._nrow).fill(1);
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }

  // Some additional methods...
}
```

This works, however, due to `Object.assign()`, I lose the typings on `values`:

```
const rawData = {x : [1, 2, 3, 4], y: [5, 6, 7, 8]}   
const data = new Dataframe(rawData)
data.x // Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Dataframe'
```

Is there any way for the class instance to inherit the properties of the `values` object? Or a different way of solving the problem altogether?

Comment: This is usually a bad idea. It's best to favor composition over inheritance and accept your array as a property of your class instead. Like this: https://tsplay.dev/w6p4vm. If you willing to accept that as an answer then let me know and I will write one up later.

Comment: You can use a static factory method to create instances instead of allowing external construction like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPgkzm). Does that address your question? If so, I can write it up as one — if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Given the error, "it works" seems like a stretch.

Comment: @AlexWayne yeah that's not too bad, I would prefer if I did not have to access the arrays as a nested property i.e. `data.values.x`, `data.values.y` but instead `data.x`, `data.y`, but I accept that there may be no neat way of doing it.

Comment: @CraigHicks It's type error not runtime error, I should've been more specific

Comment: I like Chris Hamiltons answer, because it addresses hiding the implementation keys `_nrow`, etc.  I had never heard of the `public` keyword being used in the constructor like that - very interesting.  There is no way to do Typescript type checking with dynamically passed array "labels", and Typescript is hard coded to check the explicit keys written in the class declaration.  Oh sorry - it's Javascript with type checking - not typescript - but same principle anyway.

Comment: Why would one want to derive (extend) subtypes explicitly from `Object` at all? There is no benefit to it since the explicit super call does not add anything new to the already implicitly happening inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a logical contradiction there, since `Record<string, any[]>` implies all string keys have array values. But you are also trying to add other string properties that do not have array values.

I'd recommend just making `values` a property of the class with the `public` keyword.

```js
class Dataframe extends Object {
  _nrow: number;
  _ncol: number;
  _identity: number[];

  constructor(public values: Record<string, any[]>) {
    super();
    this._nrow = values[Object.keys(values)[0]].length;
    this._ncol = Object.keys(values).length;
    this._identity = Array(this._nrow).fill(1);
  }

  // Some additional methods...
}

const rawData = {x : [1, 2, 3, 4], y: [5, 6, 7, 8]};
const data = new Dataframe(rawData);
console.log(data.values.x);
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiYBcwDMBOYC2BTaWAeCWAdgCYwDyARgFZbALQDeAUNNAPpGoD2A7gFzQiAVwyUsqANysORYNxCCRYidLbsAliWIINCAJ5LR41AG0AutJnyiEBKmH1uqABQAHYZRAbg0AG5gIMJYEIIASnTOJAA8dqgaRADmADTQYET6FgB8AJRMMmwQwm4SLjlqbNAIABYaEAB0nDy80AC8-oHBEKZUtPT1ANZY%20hAuAUEhOaYADObm9SDEiTUVbDV1jXIKbdC9dAiDw6PjXTkLSysFVbUNmtpEugY7AIKo6Pou67dcfGfIGiAQC4AIzlGQAX2YMgA9NDoABlbjYNIkEh6DTcIiBaDYGrcMj1QnMSHMGx2aDoXjwJA7Rh4aCCUzA1IAJlSAGZUgAWcypQzQUwAVlSADZUgB2VIADnM4OkZIYJEQYB2RCwLWpKHQ2BclM1YLJCiwC24iRcSqQ9ROIXqeHKQA)